# PHP - How to get a list of class's member function?

Tags: php

If I know class's name. Is there a way to know class's member function list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[get_class_methods()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) is your friend

Comment: it looks simple and better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's reflection API to get all kinds of useful information about classes.

Here's some tutorials:

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/4/0

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-the-php-reflection-api-for-fun-and-profit